# Multiple ORDER BY within CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a select statement which ends in the following:

```
order by case @pcsort
            when '' then compcode asc
            else received asc, compcode asc
        end
```

Basically I need it if `@pcsort` is ' ' then order by `compcode`, otherwise order by `received` and `compcode` in that order.

Any ideas?

Comment: What are the datatypes of `compcode` and `received`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will do what you want *assuming* datatypes are compatible

```
order by
    case @pcsort
            when '' then compcode
            else received
    end ASC, 
    compcode ASC
```

More generally, you need one CASE per sort column assuming datatypes are compatible

```
order by
    case @pcsort
            when '' then compcode
            else received
    end ASC, 
    case @pcsort
           --safe to sort on same column agaon , or use a constant
            when '' then compcode or <constant of same type as compcode>
            else compcode
    end ASC
```

Where datatypes are incompatible, you need more cases and a lot of constants

```
order by
case @pcsort
        when '' then compcode
        else <constant of same type as compcode>
end ASC, 
    case @pcsort
        when '' then <constant of same type as received>
        else received
end ASC, 
case @pcsort
        when '' then <constant of same type as compcode>
        else compcode
end ASC
```